# How to avoid cross-origin access errors

Tags: javascript, css

In my code I am paring some CSS rules with code like below:

```
const sheet = style.sheet;
const length = sheet ? sheet.rules.length : 0;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result.push(sheet.rules[i].cssText);
}
```

but it is causing cross-origin access errors (COMPONENT ERROR: CSSStyleSheet.rules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet) since some CSS styles rules have url which points to external site.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    src: url("https://my_server.com/fonts/OpenSans.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

Now it is causing errors and crashing the whole app. I am trying if there is a way to just avoid this (but not fix it).I tried to put the code inside a try catch block, but still triggering the error. Is there a way to make it fail siliently?

Comment: What exactly is failing? CORS requests should not crash your website, the CSS will just not look what you want it to.

Comment: I expect adding a [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) to the `<link>` and making sure the server for the CSS provides a suitable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header will resolve it; but I don't have the time to build a test case to make sure right now.

Comment: The code shown does nothing but read the style sheet. I don't believe the problem is in the `@font-face`'s `src` property's `url`, but rather in the HTML's `<link href="<some external url>"....`. Because you're not allowed to access that URL's source

Comment: In the log, it looks like it fails exactly at the line const length = sheet ? sheet.rules.length : 0; , the error message is "COMPONENT ERROR: CSSStyleSheet.rules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet", I am only paring <style> node in my code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the font-face declaration. As the error says, you are not allowed to access the stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

The server is configured to not allow cross origin access. A request is considered cross-origin if the website requesting the resource is not the same domain, port or protocol as the webserver providing the resource.

If you want to allow cross-origin access, then the server must implement the CORS protocol, which namely involves 2 things:

1. Respond to requests with `Access-Control` http headers, e.g: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myOtherServer.com`
2. Respond to the `OPTIONS` request with `Access-Control` headers. The `OPTIONS` response should have no body.

If you don't have control over the server to set the response, then you either need to request your administrator to configure the server for you or use a proxy server.

Further reading:

- https://breautek.com/articles/enabling-cors.html (Disclaimer: I'm the author. It involves around Cordova webviews, but the same concept applies)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS